# Tricky steam observable merge in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I could use a bit of help. I'm trying to an experiment where I start my ajax request on mouseenters of my button, but only consume the result of that request if the user clicks (or if the request hasn't finished yet when the user clicks, consume the result as soon as it does). If the user leaves the button without clicking, the request should be cancelled.

Where I'm stuck is how to merge the click stream with the request stream. I cannot use withLatestFrom, because then if the request finishes after the click, it will not be consumed. I also cannot use combineLatest, because then if any click has occurred in the past, the the request will be consumed, even if I'm currently just mousing over.
Would love some guidance. It's been a fun problem to think about but I'm stuck

```
const fetchContent = (url) => {
  const timeDelay$ = Rx.Observable.timer(1000); // simulating a slow request
  const request$ =  Rx.Observable.create(observer =>
    fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' })
      .then(json => {
         observer.onNext('res')
         observer.onCompleted()
      })
      .catch(e => observer.onError())
  )
  return timeDelay$.concat(request$)
}
const hover$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'mouseenter')
const leave$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'mouseleave')
const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'click')

const hoverRequest$ = hover$
  .flatMap(e =>
    fetchContent(e.target.getAttribute('href'))
      .takeUntil(leave$.takeUntil(click$))
  )

const displayData$ = click$
  .combineLatest(hoverRequest$)

displayData$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: sounds like what `trial.js` library does. Cf. https://github.com/MarkoCen/trial-js. Don't know if they do with rxjs though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll take a look at it. I was more building this out as an experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't terribly far off actually. You are just missing the inclusion of `zip` really. Since what you really need for propagation is for *both* a mouse click *and* the request to complete. By zipping the request and the mouse click event you can make sure that neither emits without the other.

```
const hover$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'mouseenter');
const leave$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'mouseleave');
const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'click');


//Make sure only the latest hover is emitting requests
hover$.flatMapLatest(() => {

  //The content request
  const pending$ = fetchContent();

  //Only cancel on leave if no click has been made
  const canceler$ = leave$.takeUntil(click$);

  //Combine the request result and click event so they wait for each other
  return Rx.Observable.zip(pending$, click$, (res, _) => res)

               //Only need the first emission
               .take(1)

               //Cancel early if the user leaves the button
               .takeUntil(canceler$);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could conceptualize this as three events (hover, leave, click as you call them) triggering three actions (emit request, cancel request, pass request result) modifying a state (request? pass request?).

Now this is done in a rush on a sunday evening, but with a little bit of luck , something like this could work :

```
function label(str) {return function(x){var obj = {}; obj[str] = x; return obj;}}
function getLabel(obj) {return Object.keys(obj)[0];}
const hover$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'mouseenter').map(label('hover'));
const leave$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'mouseleave').map(label('leave'));
const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myButton, 'click').map(label('click'));

var initialState = {request : undefined, response : undefined, passResponse : false};

var displayData$ = Rx.Observable.merge(hover$, leave$, click$)
  .scan(function (state, intent){
          switch (getLabel(intent)) {
            case 'hover' : 
              if (!state.request) {
                state.request = someRequest;
                state.response$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(executeRequest(someRequest));
              }
            break;
            case 'leave' : 
              if (state.request && !state.passResponse) cancelRequest(someRequest);
              state.passResponse = false;
            break;
            case 'click' :
              if (!state.request) {
                state.response$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(executeRequest(someRequest));
              }
              state.passResponse = true;
          }
        }, initial_state)
  .filter(function (state){return state.passResponse;})
  .pluck('response$')
  .concatAll()
```